# Adding/Deleting data values from a multiselect

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Currently I have a multiselect option in my edit page where at first it should display all the existing values in the database as already checked and once the user removes a selected value, it should be removed from the database and if it is already not there in the database, it should be added to the database. Currently this is my code:

View class:

```
<select name="curations[]" id="curations" multiple class="form-control multiselects" <?php echo (isset($read) ? $read:''); ?> multiple>
<?php $checked = array();
    foreach($get_curation as $key => $value){ 
    $checked[]=$value['curations_id'];
    }
    if($curations){ foreach($curations as $cur){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $cur['id']; ?>" <?php echo in_array($cur['id'], $checked) ? 'selected' : 'selected'; ?>><?php echo $cur['title']; ?></option>
<?php }
} ?>
</select>
```

Controller Class:

```
if ($this->input->post('curations') != '') {
    $curationsPost = $this->input->post('curations');
    $curationsArray = array();
    $c = 0;
    foreach($curationsPost as $cp){
        if ($cp != ''){
        $curationsArray[$c]['listings_id']= $id;
        $curationsArray[$c]['curations_id']= $cp;

        $c++;
    }
}

    if(count($curationsArray) > 0){
        $this->listings_model->update_curations($curationsArray);
    }
}
```

Model class:

```
function update_curations($curationsArray, $id)
{
    $this->db->where('listings_id', $id);
    $q = $this->db->get('crm_property_curation');
    $this->db->reset_query();

    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        $this->db->where('listings_id', $id);
        $this->db->update_batch('crm_property_curation', $curationsArray);
    } else {
        $this->db->insert_batch('crm_property_curation', $curationsArray);
    }
}
```

As of now by default it displays all the values as selected eventhough the values aren't present in the database and everytime that I submit the form, it does not update the entry in my database. So basically what I need here is 2 things, 1 is that it shouldn't show everything initially when user enters the page and only show the selected values, and 2 is that when the form is submitted, it should insert the nonduplicate selected values and delete the unselected values which as of now it only inserts the values initially.

The database holds 2 columns listings_id which is the id of the listing and curations_id which is the id of the option selected:

[image]

`var_dump($this->input->post('curations'));` gives `array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "6" [1]=> string(2) "19" }` and

`var_dump($curationsArray);` gives `array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["listings_id"]=> string(4) "6253" ["curations_id"]=> string(1) "6" } [1]=> array(2) { ["listings_id"]=> string(4) "6253" ["curations_id"]=> string(2) "19" } }`

Comment: Simplest solution: Delete all records from intermediate table before inserting, by `listings_id`.

Comment: @ThanhDao Okay so this worked, but now if I suppose unselect all the options and submit, then it retains the previous selected options in the database. This is my current model function:
`$this->db->where('listings_id', $id);
$this->db->delete("crm_property_curation");
$this->db->insert_batch('crm_property_curation', $curationsArray);`

Comment: Simply move `if` block of checking count `count($curationsArray) > 0` to before `insert_batch` statement